# Doctrine2 Annotation

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I have a little problem with doctrine. I have an entity "a" with a annotation to entity "b".
I configured a cache for all my results. When i make a foreach for every "a"-entity and ask for value "b" there are many queries generated.

Which function will be used internally by doctrine to find the "b" entity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you need to analyze your scenario. In many cases you well need to load the entire repository, for example, if you want to display all the available options for a select input. At this case, you could use [EAGER association](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/working-with-objects.html#by-eager-loading)

```
<?php
/**
 * @ManyToOne(targetEntity="B", cascade={"all"}, fetch="EAGER")
 */
private $b;
```

Comment: Thanks. But my problem is, that i have a own DoctrineEntityRepository implementation for defining my cache. If i do something like ```$a->getB();``` nothing is cached so i dont know which function is used internally. Is there just a query generated from the annotations or is a pre-defined find(), findBy() or something else used?